# Frequency dependence of Schwinger limit

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, frequency, pair-production

Schwinger estimated a field of $10^{18}$ volts per meter as a point of "vacuum breakdown", over which spontaneous generation of positron-electron pairs becomes energetically favourable.

But it is my understanding this to be a DC / infrared limit estimate, the vacuum response should become limited at higher frequencies, hence at (say) optical frequencies the breakdown voltage should be much higher

Is there an heuristic equation to estimate this breakdown field in terms of field frequency?